# v-model not binding correctly to array of objects

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am trying to use v-model to bind each `cofounder_template` object inside the `cofounders` array to the form inputs based on the number of cofounders selected.

**For Example:**

When `current_num_cofounders = 3`

then `cofounders = [{cofounder_template},{cofounder_template},{cofounder_template}]`

**Problem Experiencing:**

The problem I am currently encountering is when I input a value inside `cofounders[0].firstname`, all the other `cofounders[n].firstname` will have the same value. 
I am not sure why this is happening. Please advise what I did wrong.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mr_prince00/u1yxq5b3/)

**HTML**

```
<form id="app" class="container"> 
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="founders">Number of Cofounders</label>
            <select id="founders" class="form-control" @change="changeCofounders($event.target.value)">
                <option value="0" selected>Choose...</option>
                <option v-for="n in 20" :key="n" :value="n">{{ n }}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cofounders" v-if="cofounders.length > 0" v-for="(cofounder,i) in cofounders" :key="i">
        <h4 class="font-weight-bold" >Cofounder {{i + 1}}</h4>
        <hr>
        <br>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first_name" name="first_name[]" v-model="cofounders[i].first_name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="last_name" name="last_name[]" v-model="cofounders[i].last_name">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="phone">Phone</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone[]" v-model="cofounders[i].phone">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="email_address">Email</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email_address" name="email[]" v-model="cofounders[i].email">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data(){
        return {
            current_num_cofounders: 0,
            cofounders: [],
            cofounder_template: {
                first_name: '',
                last_name: '',
                email: '',
                phone: '',
            }
        }
    },
    created(){
        console.log('main running')
    },
    methods:{
        changeCofounders (str_num) {
            let selected_num_cofounders = parseInt(str_num)

            //add when current is less than selected
            if(this.current_num_cofounders < selected_num_cofounders){
                this.cofounders = Array(selected_num_cofounders).fill(this.cofounder_template)
                this.current_num_cofounders = selected_num_cofounders
                console.log(this.cofounders)
            } 
            //remove when current is greater than selected
            if(this.current_num_cofounders > selected_num_cofounders){
                this.cofounders.splice(0, selected_num_cofounders)
                this.current_num_cofounders = selected_num_cofounders
                console.log(this.cofounders)
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You assigned the same object to all array elements so that's why they changes simultaneously. Solution is to create its own template copy for each array element:

```
this.cofounders = [...Array(selected_num_cofounders).keys()]
  .map(x => Object.assign({}, this.cofounder_template))
```

Comment: This makes so much sense. Thank you for you help!!